# Different click event on 2 DIVs that are one in an other

Tags: javascript, events

Here is the code that I have tested:

```
div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.setAttribute('style','width:500px;height:500px;background-color:green;');
div1.addEventListener('click',function()
    {
    alert('div1');
    });

div2 = document.createElement('div');
div1.appendChild(div2);
div2.setAttribute('style','width:200px;height:200px;background-color:red;');
div2.addEventListener('click',function()
    {
    alert('div2');
    });
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div1);
```

The problem is, that i need only one function call, if i click the div that is inside. I don´t wish to get function from the parent div, how is it possible to make?

Comment: I would recommend only having on function for your actual click bindings since your current example only needs one.  Otherwise if you need more stuff please provide some context. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
div2.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();// prevents  event from bubbling to parents.
        alert('div2');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

event.stopPropagation() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation is what you need to call on the internal div click event this keeps the event from continuing to parent event bindings.

Comment: It's not a jQuery question, `stopPropagation` is vanilla js event function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the event propagaton:

```
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.setAttribute('style', 'width:500px;height:500px;background-color:green;');
div1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('div1');
});

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div1.appendChild(div2);
div2.setAttribute('style', 'width:200px;height:200px;background-color:red;');
div2.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    alert('div2');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDR9R/1/